# Query dynamic data from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

I want to query data from a specific SQL column that meets certain criteria.  This column contains free form text entered by a user.  The user can enter whatever he/she wants, but always includes a URL which may be entered anywhere within the free form text.

Each URL is similar and contains consistent elements, such as the domain, but also references a unique "article ID" number within the URL.  Think of these numbers as referencing knowledge base articles.

The article ID is a different number depending on the article used and new articles are regularly created.

I need a query identifying all of these article ID numbers within the URLs.  The only means I've developed so far is to use SUBSTRING to count characters until reaching the article ID number.  This is unreliable since users don't always include the URL at the beginning.  It would be better if I could tell SUBSTRING to count from the beginning of the URL regardless of where it resides within the text.

For example, it begins counting whenever it finds 'HTTP://' or a common keyword each URL contains.  Another option would be if I could extract the URL into it's own table.  I've yet to figure out how to execute either of these ideas inside SQL.

The following is what I have so far.

```
select 
    scl.number, 
    ol.accountnum, 
    scl.opendate as CallOpenDate, 
    sce.opendate as NoteEntryDate, 
    sce.notes, 
    substring(sce.notes, 102, 4) as ArticleID, 
    sclcc.pmsoft, 
    ol.territorydesc

from (select * from supportcallevent as sce
    where sce.opendate > '2014-04-01 00:00:00.000') as sce

inner join supportcalllist as scl on scl.SupportCallID=sce.supportcallid
inner join organizationlist as ol on ol.partyid=scl.partyid
inner join supportcalllist_custcare as sclcc on sclcc.supportcallid=scl.supportcallid

where sce.notes like '%http://askus.how%'

order by ol.territorydesc, scl.number;
```

Comment: can you give an example URL?

Comment: There are two main variations of the URLs.  Here are two examples [URL1][1] and [URL2][2]:

[1]: http://askus.howtodoit.com/system/templates/selfservice/company/#agent/portal/1001/article/6837/Is-There-an-Instruction-Manual-or-a-Training-Workbook-21-APR-2014?fromQuery=needs a company manual


[2]: http://csq-askus.howtodoit.com/system/templates/selfservice/company/#agent/portal/1001/article/3868/How-to-Add-Diagnostic-Codes-17-APR-2014?fromQuery=diagnosticcodes diagnostic codes in software
@sion_corn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CHARINDEX` function to find the URL in the string and start the substring from there.

This example will get the next 4 digits after the url:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @find VARCHAR(100)

SET @str = 'waawhbu aoffawh http://askus.how/1111 auwhauowd'
SET @find = 'http://askus.how/'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@str,CHARINDEX(@find, @str)+17,4)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33717/0)

Comment: Great answer, you might include how to use the substring with the charindex for completeness.

Comment: It looks as though this example requires the text encompassing the URL to be included in the query.  However, the text surrounding each URL will differ.  Is it possible to incorporate a wildcard?

Comment: Are you looking to get data after the last slash in the url? if so, you can use `CHARINDEX` again to find the last slash in the url and then pull whatever number of characters after that... you could even use `CHARINDEX` a third time to find the first space following the URL and just pull everything between the last slash and first space

Comment: The account number I want is later in the URL, yes.  A typical URL looks something like this:  
( http://askus.howtodoit.com/system/tem...01/article/6837/... )  

There's also a prefix variation like http://csq-askus.how...  Other than the "csq-" variation, the rest of the URL follows the same pattern.  What I'm saying is that I understand the "SET @str" clause in your example to be including the variable text surrounding the URL.  If the text surrounding the URL is required for this clause to work, then I'd have to write a unique query for every known entry including a URL.

Comment: Text surrounding the URL is not required for this method to work... Just plug it right into your query. `SUBSTRING(sce.notes, CHARINDEX(<your url to match minus the article_id>, sce.notes)+LEN(<your url to match minus the article_id>),4)  as ArticleID,`

Comment: The 6837 in the URL of my previous comment is an example of an article number I'm trying to extract from each entry.  I don't know how many entries there are nor how many article IDs so I can't write queries for every entry including a unique SET @str line for each.  I want to write a query searching an entire table for all entries containing one of these many URLs and pull the article ID from each different URL.  The text surrounding each URL will vary in content and length.  The end goal is to create a report showing how many times each article is used.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I was just showing how `CHARINDEX` works, not giving you the exact syntax to use. I was expecting you to look at how it works and work that in your query. My previous comment should help with working it into your query.

Comment: I get it now.  You're a lifesaver.  Sorry for making you spell it out for me.  I'm a bit of a novice.